# EXEC sp_who2 LastBatch showing future date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sp-who2

I am receiving future dates in LastBatch column when i run `EXEC sp_who2` on SQL Server.

for example most of the SPIDs have 5/14 as LastBatch date. (which means 2014)

And my first 20 row has 04/28 as LastBatch date. (which means 2028)

Any idea why i am seeing future dates in this column?

Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting whats going on.

04/28 indicates 28/04 (28th of April) - not 2028.

5/14 indicates 14th May - Todays date.

Comment: You are right. I was exporting this data into excel and excel converts it as 2028! I just figured it out. Thanks.